# Creating Viewmodels and mapping to entities

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating ViewModels for my entities. The FirmViewModel contains two list collections called Addressess and Websites. I have also created viewmodels for Addresses and Websites. At the moment in the controller code, I am getting trouble assigning Addresses and Wesbite collections 
 of the Firm Entity to FirmViewModels Addresses and Websites collection. Its says cant cast it implicitly. This is the line in the controller that it complains   Addresses = firm.Addresses; How do aassign

```
Systems.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Manager.Model.Address> to Systems.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Manager.WebUI.ViewModels.AddressViewModel>
```

NewFirmViewModel

```
public class NewFirmViewModel
{
    public int FirmId { get; set; }

    public string FirmName { get; set;}

    public Nullable<DateTime> DateFounded { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AddressViewModel> Addresses { get; set; }

    public ICollection<WebsiteViewModel> Websites { get; set; }

    public bool hasIntralinks { get; set; }
}
```

AddressViewModel

```
        public class AddressViewModel
    {
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public string Line1 { get; set; }
        public string Line2 { get; set; }
        public string Line3 { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public bool IsHeadOffice { get; set; }
        public int FirmId { get; set; }
    }
```

WebsiteViewModel

```
 public class WebsiteViewModel
    {
        private int FirmWebsiteId { get; set; }
        private string WebsiteUrl { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public int FirmId { get; set; }
    }
```

Entities - Firm

```
public class FIRM: Entity,IHasAUMs<FIRM_AUM> 
{
    public FIRM()
    {
        //this.FIRM_PERSON = new HashSet<FIRM_PERSON>();
        this.MANAGERSTRATEGies = new HashSet<MANAGERSTRATEGY>();
        this.FIRM_ACTIVITY = new HashSet<FIRM_ACTIVITY>();
        this.FIRM_AUMs = new HashSet<FIRM_AUM>();
        this.FIRM_REGISTRATION = new HashSet<FIRM_REGISTRATION>();
        //this.ACTIVITies = new HashSet<ACTIVITY>();
        Addresses = new HashSet<ADDRESS>();
        //People = new HashSet<PERSON>();   
       // Websites = new HashSet<FIRM_WEBSITE>();
    }

    //public decimal ID { get; set; }
    //
    //
    //
    //
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string SHORT_NAME { get; set; }
    public string ALTERNATE_NAME { get; set; }
    public string WEBSITE { get; set; }
    public string WEBSITE_USERNAME { get; set; }
    public string WEBSITE_PASSWORD { get; set; }
    public bool? INTRALINKS_FIRM { get; set; }        
    public string NOTES_TEXT { get; set; }
    public string NOTES_HTML { get; set; }
    public string HISTORY_TEXT { get; set; }
    public string HISTORY_HTML { get; set; }

    public string HISTORY_SUM_TEXT { get; set; }
    public string HISTORY_SUM_HTML { get; set; }

    public Nullable<decimal> OLD_ORG_REF { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> SOURCE_ID { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = PermalConstants.DateFormat)]
    public Nullable<DateTime> DATE_FOUNDED { get; set; }

    public virtual  ICollection<ADDRESS> Addresses { get; set; }

  //  public ICollection<FIRM_WEBSITE> Websites { get; set; }
    // public ICollection<PERSON> People { get; set; }

    //public SOURCE SOURCE { get; set; }
    // public ICollection<FIRM_PERSON> FIRM_PERSON { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MANAGERSTRATEGY> MANAGERSTRATEGies { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FIRM_ACTIVITY> FIRM_ACTIVITY { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FIRM_REGISTRATION> FIRM_REGISTRATION { get; set; }
    //public ICollection<ACTIVITY> ACTIVITies { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FIRM_WEBSITE> Websites { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> KEY_CONTACT_ID { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<FIRM_AUM> AUMs
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FIRM_AUMs;
        }
    }
    public ICollection<FIRM_AUM> FIRM_AUMs { get; set; }
}


ADDRESS




public class ADDRESS : Entity
    {
        public ADDRESS()
        {
            // DATE_CREATED = DateTime.Now;
        }


        public string LINE1 { get; set; }
        public string LINE2 { get; set; }
        public string LINE3 { get; set; }
        public int CITY_ID { get; set; }
        public string POSTAL_CODE { get; set; }
        public string SWITCHBOARD_INT { get; set; }
        public string NOTES { get; set; }
        public int? OLD_ADDRESS_REF { get; set; }
        public int? SOURCE_ID { get; set; }

        public int FIRM_ID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("FIRM_ID")]
        public FIRM FIRM { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CITY_ID")]
        public CITY City { get; set; }

        public ICollection<PERSON> People { get; set; }

        // public SOURCE SOURCE { get; set; }

        public bool IS_HEAD_OFFICE { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string AddressBlurb
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Join(",", new[] { LINE1, LINE2, City != null ? City.NAME : "", City != null && City.Country != null ? City.Country.NAME : "" }.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)));
            }
        }
    }



FIRM_WEBSITE



  public class FIRM_WEBSITE : Entity
    {
        public FIRM_WEBSITE()
        {

        }
        private string _WEBSITE_URL;

        public string WEBSITE_URL
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_WEBSITE_URL))
                    return _WEBSITE_URL;
                try
                {

                    var ubuilder = new System.UriBuilder(_WEBSITE_URL ?? "");

                    return ubuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
                }
                catch (UriFormatException ex)
                {
                    return _WEBSITE_URL;
                }

            }
            set { _WEBSITE_URL = value; }
        }

        public string USERNAME { get; set; }
        public string PASSWORD { get; set; }


        public int FIRM_ID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("FIRM_ID")]
        public FIRM FIRM { get; set; }
    }
```

FirmController

```
 public class FirmController : ApiControllerBase
        {
            [HttpGet]
            [Route("api/Firm/{id}")]
            public IHttpActionResult Details(int id)
            {
                var viewModel = GetFirmViewModel(id);
                return Ok(viewModel);
            }       


        private NewFirmViewModel GetFirmViewModel(int id)
            {
                var firmSvc = GetService<FIRM>();
                var firm = firmSvc.GetWithIncludes(id, f => f.Addresses, f => f.Websites);


                var firmVm = new NewFirmViewModel()
                {
                    FirmId =  firm.ID,
                    FirmName =  firm.NAME,
                    DateFounded  =  firm.DATE_FOUNDED,
                    Addresses = firm.Addresses;



                };
    }




   public virtual T GetWithIncludes(int id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] paths)
        {
            try
            {
                using (new TimedLogger(_perfLogger, GetCompletedText("GetWithIncludes"), typeof(T).Name))
                {
                    return Authorize(_repo.GetWithIncludes(id, paths), AuthAccessLevel.Read);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Log(ex); throw; }
        }
```

Comment: You probably need to show what code your `firmSvc.GetWithIncludes()` method signature. My guess would be that is what the compiler is pointing you towards.

Comment: added the code to the post

Comment: I think i have got it. Just tried Addresses = firm.Addresses.Select(x => new AddressViewModel(){AddressId = x.ID , Line1 = x.LINE1, Line2 = x.LINE2, Line3 = x.LINE3,FirmId = x.FIRM_ID}).ToList()